# MYSQL: Select Then Update. Double Processing Issue

Tags: mysql, google-checkout

**The Issue:**

I am building a google checkout callback interface.  The issue I am having is that google sends 2 responses at the same time back to the site and the site processes both of them, so I end up with 2 updates.  The code is written to check if the entry exists, and if it does not insert or update as needed.

The time stamps will be identical and it will post 2 transactions.  I had the database at Innodb, but I changed it to MyISAM in hopes that it would resolve the issue.

**Question:**

Is it possible to have an SQL query select and then update on a conditional.  Or is there something else I can do to get around this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `EXIST` to perform your update only of your `select` return a result

```
 UPDATE TABLE1 SET col=`value` 
 where exists (select 1 from TABLE2 where condition)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to clarify what you mean by "Google sends 2 responses at the same time".

I'm assuming you are referring to [Google Checkout API](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Processing#notification_api) - and if so, each *notification* Google sends represents "something". You have to identify what the `Notification` is - in other words, you maybe "fixing" an issue that doesn't exist and are doing so based on your perception of what Google sends (rather than noticing that they, each `Notification`, are distinct).

Hth....

Comment: It was pinging with 2 new-order-notifications and causing an overlap when I put the information into the database.  I resolved the issue.  I would post it but I do not believe it would be of much help as its a very specific situation.